# What exactly does SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) do?

Tags: sql

I used the following query and it returned what I wanted it to return, but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around what the query is doing.

Query is nothing fancier than what's in the title: `select distinct(count(*)) from table1`

Comment: The `Distinct` is not needed.  It's getting a single `Count` of all data in `Table1` and then getting the distinct counts (which there would only be one).  You can get the same results via: `Select Count(*) From Table1`

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM table1`? That would make more sense and the `DISTINCT` would actually perform a useful function.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a SQL keyword, _not_ a function as `DISTINCT()`.  This is a mistake people make often, which clouds its real purpose and the fact that it acts over the _entire_ rowset rather than just the column name it is nearest.

Comment: (+1) @MichaelBerkowski but `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM table1` would differ from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1` only if there were duplicate records (for some reason)?

Comment: Ah not sure why I thought the Distinct(count(*)) was different from count(*). And I'm not sure if count(distinct * ) works in other DB engines, but it doesn't in Teradata

Comment: Ah wait, `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` is a syntax error in MySQL as well. A column name has to be specified as `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`

Answer (score 4):

Distinct is not required in your SQL ,as you are going to get only result, count(*) without group by clause returns, count of all rows within that table.

Hence try this :

```
select count(*) from table1
```

Distinct is used for finding distinct values from a group of values:

say you have table1 , with column1 as :

```
Column1
----------
a
a
b
b
a
c
```

following sqls are run you will get output as :

1)    `select count(*) from table1`

output :6

2)    `select distinct(count(*)) from table1`

output :6

3)   `select count( distinct column1) from table1`

output :3

Usually distinct is used inside count preferably with a particular column .

```
select count( distinct column_name_n ) from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

The distinct is redundant... Select Count(*) with only one table can only generate one value, so distinct (which would eliminate duplicates) is irelelvant.

If you had multiple outputs, (if for example you were grouping on something) then it would cause the query to only display one output row for every distinct value of  count(*) that would other wise be generated...

if, for example, you had

```
 name
 Bob
 Bob
 Bob
 Bob
 Mary
 Mary
 Mary
 Mary
 Dave
 Dave
 Al
 George
```

then

```
 select count(*) 
 From table 
 group By name
```

would result in

```
    4
    4
    2
    1
    1
```

but

```
 select distinct count(*) 
 From table 
 group By name
```

would result in

```
    4
    2
    1
```